# Two RecyclerView inside the same Scrollview, one does not show content

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm facing a problem with two `RecyclerView` inside the same `ScrollView` (I also tried the same with a `NestestScrollView`). Inside the `ScrollView`, I have also some other `View` objects that form a kind of "header section" of the fragment. Then, I would like to show a horizontal list of RecyclerView, and finally, above the horizontal list, a vertical list of other RecyclerView. However, only the horizontal one is correctly visualized. Even though the `Adapter` of the vertical one is correctly initialized with some objects, when I run the application, the vertical list is empty. I think it is a problem related to my layout.

This is my `.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profile_coordinator"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <!-- Here I have some other views (ImageView, TextView, etc.) -->


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/active_promos"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"/>

            <!-- Horizontal List of RecyclerView -->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/promo_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/news"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"/>

            <!-- Vertical List of RecyclerView -->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/news_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Since the objects to show are the same (but the semantics is different), I'm using the same `Adapter` class that loads two different xml layout according to the type of object to show.

This is the `Adapter.java`:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private List<NewsPromotion> newsPromotions;
private boolean promos;

public NewsAdapter(List<NewsPromotion> newsPromotions, boolean promos) {
    this.newsPromotions = newsPromotions;
    this.promos = promos;
}

public void setData(List<NewsPromotion> newsPromotions){
    this.newsPromotions = newsPromotions;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(promos) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.promo_recyclerview_item,
                parent, false);

        viewHolder = new PromoViewHolder(mView);

    }else {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item_row,
                parent, false);

        viewHolder = new NewsViewHolder(mView);
    }

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    Log.d("Adapter", newsPromotions.get(position).title);

    if(promos){
        PromoViewHolder viewHolder = (PromoViewHolder) holder;
        Picasso.get().load(RestClient.BASE_IMAGE_URL + newsPromotions.get(position).image).into(viewHolder.mImage);
    }else {


        NewsViewHolder viewHolder = (NewsViewHolder) holder;

        Picasso.get().load(RestClient.BASE_IMAGE_URL + newsPromotions.get(position).image).into(viewHolder.mImage);
        viewHolder.mTitle.setText(newsPromotions.get(position).title);
        viewHolder.mDescription.setText(newsPromotions.get(position).content);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newsPromotions.size();
}

public class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView mImage;
    TextView mTitle;
    TextView mDescription;

    private NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    }
}

public class PromoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView mImage;

    private PromoViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    }
}
```

}

And the following is how I initialize the two adapters in the Fragment:

```
RecyclerView promoRecycleView = activity.findViewById(R.id.promo_recyclerview);
promoAdapter = new NewsAdapter(new ArrayList<NewsPromotion>(), true);
promoRecycleView.setAdapter(promoAdapter);

RecyclerView newsRecycleView = activity.findViewById(R.id.news_recyclerview);
newsAdapter = new NewsAdapter(new ArrayList<NewsPromotion>(), false);
newsRecycleView.setAdapter(newsAdapter);
```

Finally, this is how I send the object to the adapters:

```
promoAdapter.setData(promos);
promoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

newsAdapter.setData(news);
newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Hi. Maybe, problem with adapter?

Answer (score 0):

If you would check documentation on the RecyclerView, you will see that you need to specify size of the list. There is no wrap content for `RecyclerView`, because it's dynamic widget. So you would need to align your implementation for something like next.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/profile_coordinator"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <!-- Here I have some other views (ImageView, TextView, etc.) -->


        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/active_promos"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"/>

            <!-- Horizontal List of RecyclerView -->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/promo_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/news"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"/>

            <!-- Vertical List of RecyclerView -->
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/news_recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Checked, but I get the same results (no objects are shown by the second `RecyclerView`).

Comment: @MattiaCampana . Then you are doing something wrong with your `Adapter` because example above if perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your adapter and item_layout. Because your given layout is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

No issue with your layout i have run in myAppliaction, some issue in Adapter, please post/paste your activity and adapter code.

Comment: Please, check my updated question with the Adapter code.

Comment: //one line is missing in your  onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) method 
// after NewsViewHolder viewHolder = (NewsViewHolder) holder;
//add below line 
NewsPromotion newsPromotions =  newsPromotions.get(position);

Comment: Please check if you have added layout manager for you Recycler view RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());                         

it should look like this:
RecyclerView promoRecycleView = activity.findViewById(R.id.promo_recyclerview);
promoAdapter = new NewsAdapter(new ArrayList<NewsPromotion>(), true);   
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());  
promoRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
promoRecycleView.setAdapter(promoAdapter);